# Devise LDAP authentication dn lookup fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ldap

Trying to setup Devise LDAP authentication using devise_ldap_authenticatable gem. 
I have this code in **devise.rb**

```
config.ldap_logger = true
config.ldap_create_user = false
config.ldap_update_password = false
config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
config.ldap_check_group_membership = false
config.ldap_check_attributes = false
config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = false
config.ldap_ad_group_check = false
config.ldap_auth_username_builder =Proc.new() {|attribute, login, ldap|login+'@domain'}
```

Everything works fine in the console, I am able to bind and do a dn look up. It seems like logging in is working fine in the rails app too since devise is redirecting without any error. However this is the log I get. Seems like dn look up fails in the application and returns nothing and the user is not created either

```
LDAP dn lookup: sAMAccountName=username
LDAP search for login: sAMAccountName=username
LDAP search yielded 0 matches
Authorizing user username@domain
LDAP dn lookup: sAMAccountName=username
LDAP search for login: sAMAccountName=username
LDAP search yielded 0 matches
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Verify that the entry you expect exists using a known good tool `ldapsearch`. Use the same search parameters and BIND DN as used by the LDAP client.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you specify the LDAP connection information?

I assume in this file:
`config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml`

Probably should add that info to the question, properly santized (Do not post real IP's, passwords, etc).